# How to keep a url while viewing another page?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pagination

Check out this Example: Go to lostrolls.com and go all the way down to their pagination where it says "Mayores" if you hit that button their pagination will take you to lostrolls.com/hot/2 because their home page is actually ( lostrolls.com/hot "Hot page" ) and their homepage stay lostrolls.com. That's exactly what i want!

Comment: Lets say that i want domain.com/calientes to be my home page and i want my url stay domain.com and when i hit next on my pagination im going to be able to go to domain.com/calientes/page/2 ... just like 9gag.com does.. their homepage its 9gag.com/hot and their domain stay 9gag.com it only shows 9gag.com/hot if you click on the menu Hot to go to the Hot's page ... How can i do that?

Comment: i want to be able to see domain.com/calientes while im in domain.com like 9gag.com does...

Comment: make it a static home page, in your dashboard go to settings=>reading=>static front page=>and choose `calientes` as your static front page